# Text Fade Out Effect with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have found a nice tutorial for an "Fade Out"-effect / "Read-More"-button and it is working quite well. 
Unfortunately I'm using AngularJS to generate several containers. Like below:

```
<article class='result' ng-repeat='result in results track by $id(result)'>
        <div class="container">
                <h2>{{result.bug_id}} - {{result.short_desc}</h2>              
                <p>{{result.message}}</p>
                <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button">Show More</a></p>
        </div>
</article>
```

What do I have to change in my code to achieve the Fade-Out effect on every single container?

Comment: What is $id(result) ?

Comment: The whole project is a search engine and it returns the results with its $id

Comment: Why don't u use ng-animate https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate?

Comment: Didn't even think about it. Thanks for the advise, I'll try it.